# Trigger to Update row with information

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, plsqldeveloper

Hello to  everyone i'm trying to do a trigger to update the information in a table, but this table has information, and this information comes from this procedure storage

```
create or replace procedure insertar (new_bod int, new_arti int, cant int)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO bod_arti (bod_id, arti_id, cant)
       VALUES (new_bod , new_arti, new_cant);
END
```

in this procedure bod_id is a PK from BOD table and arti_id is a PK from ARTI table when I try to insert values calling the procedure, i have an error and this is because the PK are the same.
how can I do to insert only cant in the table and adding the information? i have this trigger

```
create trigger myfirsttrigger BEFORE INSERT ON bod_arti
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE bod_arti SET cant = cant + NEW.cant WHERE bod_id = NEW.bod_id AND arti_id = NEW.arti_id
```

and when i call the procedure again with values I have already inserted I have this error

## 1442 - Can't update table 'bod_arti' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

What can i do?
Thank You!

Comment: what table you want to update?

Comment: You cant update a table on its table itself while inserting using trigger

Comment: You can use stored procedure to update inside a trigger instead.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you attempting to add a row to the table by performing an INSERT, and you also want to update all rows in the table with `(bod_id,art_id)` values that matches the new row being inserted? Very odd. Is there a unique constraint on the table? If `(bod_id,arti_id)` is unique, I suspect you might be seeking the behavior of `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY` behavior. But I'm just guessing, because from the question, it's not at all clear what you are needing to do.

Comment: What you can do is better explain what you are attempting to achieve. Sample data in the table, sample data being inserted, and the end state, what you expect the table to contain after the operation. The error message being returned is a restriction in MySQL. WIthin the context of a BEFORE INSERT trigger, it's not possible to perform an UPDATE the same table.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle PLSQL, see how you can achieve this below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertar (new_bod    INT,
                                      new_arti   INT,
                                      new_cant   INT)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO bod_arti (bod_id, arti_id, cant)
        VALUES (new_bod, new_arti, new_cant);

   COMMIT;
END;
```

***Trigger :***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myfirsttrigger
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON bod_arti
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

/*In place of writing a update you can try as below*/
--   UPDATE bod_arti
--      SET cant = cant + :NEW.cant
--    WHERE bod_id = :NEW.bod_id AND arti_id = :NEW.arti_id;

     ---Create autonomous transaction
   proc_upd(:old.bod_id ,:old.arti_id,:old.cant); 

END;
```

***Autonomous Transaction***

```
create or replace  procedure proc_upd(num1 number,num2 number, num3 number)
as
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin

   UPDATE bod_arti     
      SET cant = cant + num3       
   WHERE bod_id = num1
    AND arti_id = num2;

    commit;

END;
```

***Call multiple times:***

```
exec insertar(1,2,3);
exec insertar(4,5,6);
```

***Output:***

```
SQL> select * from bod_arti;

    BOD_ID    ARTI_ID       CANT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          6
         4          5          12
```